# Increase measurement distance of a capacitive proximity sensor - Arduino project

Tags: arduino, sensor, proximity-sensor, capacitive

I am working on a 3D tracking interface project that I found online [here](https://makezine.com/projects/a-touchless-3d-tracking-interface/).

[image]

However, instead of using my hand to track, I want to track an aluminum ball with a 2 cm radius, which is connected to ground. I am also using thin metal aluminum plates instead of foil.

I can't get the distance I need, which is about 35 cm. How do I increase the measuring distance of the plate to reach at least 35 cm?

This is the circuit:

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Capsense is not meant to be very high resolution or high gain. If you had searched the Arduino library details you should have bumped into this: http://robot-develop.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/ThereminVision-II-manual.pdf   This would be a much more suitable system to provide the increase in sensitivity you want

Answer (score 1):

The frequency is too low for a conducting area 10x bigger with  hand and more including arm.

BTW the design had a poor resolution of 2 bits or 4 levels to start with.

Try 1000 x higher frequency and increase plate gap by 1 cm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, just to be sure I understood, the gap between the plate and the edge of the wood/carton? and the frequency, you mean the one in the set in the program?

Comment: Plate edge gaps must be larger than ball.  I don’t see a design schematic so it may not be possible using an Arduino only